# How to convert double pointer matrix to a single pointer vector in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix

I have an double pointer matrix that i want to convert to a single pointer vector in c++.
here is the code:

```
int main(){
    int AA[2][2] = {1,2,3,4};
    int i,j,k;
    int kolB,barB;
    int **BB,**CC;
    int *A,*B,*C;

    BB = new int*[barB];
    CC = new int*[2];

    for(i=0;i<kolB;i++){
        BB[i] = new int[kolB];
        CC[i] = new int[kolB];
    }

    free(BB);
    free(CC);

    return 0;
}
```

i want to insert **AA value to *A, can you guys help me with this?

Comment: Don't mix `new` and `free()` please.

Comment: i get an error using malloc, so i just use this way

Comment: Use `delete[]` instead.

Comment: and how do i convert **BB to *B?

Comment: @ErwinYohanes well you just can't, you have to copy every single value, because they are not the same thing

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do? Yikes.

Comment: _"I get an error using malloc, so i just use this way"_ This is the problem with programming-by-guessing: you made it _worse_, not better. Why don't you take the approach recommended by your C++ book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you want to access each element in the double pointer array and put it in a single pointer array like this:

```
//assuming kolB,barB,**BB have been initialized
B=new int[kolB*barB];//create a one dimensional integer array to be pointed to by int* B

//then copy the value from double pointer array to this new one dimensional array
for(int i=0;i<barB;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<kolB;j++)
       B[(i*barB)+j]=BB[i][j];//you need to copy each value
```

If you are thinking of doing `B=(int*)BB;` and access it like `B[i]`, that will not work,so don't. BTW there are some interesting comments at the comment section of your question, you may want to take a look at them and improve your code.